# VS 2010 - find text in XAML editor

Tags: visual-studio-2010

In VS 2010, when searching for text in the XAML editor, the highlighted text is highlighted in the lightest gray colour when not in focus. Is it possible to change the background colour of the highlighted found item text? I've tried changing the VS theme but cannot find the property which would set this colour. In the screenshot below, the text "Text" is selected but you can barely see it and its driving me mad.
[image]

Comment: driving me mad too. I click the element in the visual designer and somewhere among the tons of XAML a little piece text "highlights" in light grey in the XAML editor window. How cool, it helps me NOT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WORKAROUND:

After clicking CTRL + F, then click on the scroll bar in the XAML to regain focus on the XAML and you'll see the find text in the correct colour!

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug that it doesn't show up as the active selection color when you perform a Find.  I didn't find a workaround for it until after VS2010 shipped, sorry :(  I'll find the Connect bug for you to vote up and then update this answer.